# Pyspark - find the oldest date in a nested collection

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, date-comparison

I have the following dataframe

```
 root
     |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer (nullable = false)
     |-- Books: array (nullable = true) 
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- DATE: TimestampType (nullable = true)
```

How to find the oldest published book for each author ? I want to retrieve the date

```
{
 "AUTHOR_ID": 1,
 "FIRST_PUBLICATION": <Date>
 "Books": "[ ... ]"
}
```

Comment: Can you share sample data along with expected output?

Comment: @wwnde I just gave my own answer (see it below), thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Many ways of doing, Lets Try window functions

```
root
 |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Books: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DATE: date (nullable = true)

+---------+--------------------------------+
|AUTHOR_ID|Books                           |
+---------+--------------------------------+
|21       |[{Stories of Mary, 2019-12-01}] |
|34       |[{Sorrows of Mary, 2019-09-01}] |
|34       |[{Sparrows of Mary, 2019-06-16}]|
|21       |[{Songs of Mary, 2017-03-14}]   |
+---------+--------------------------------+
```

Following you Edits

```
win=Window.partitionBy('AUTHOR_ID').orderBy(F.asc('Books.Date'))
df1=(
  
     df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(win)==1).where(col('rank')==1).drop('rank')#Filter by oldest date
     
     .withColumn('value', to_json(F.struct(col('AUTHOR_ID'),col('Books.Date').alias('FIRST_PUBLICATION'),'Books')))#Create json column
     
    ).select('value').show(truncate=False)


+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"AUTHOR_ID":21,"FIRST_PUBLICATION":["2017-03-14"],"Books":[{"NAME":"Songs of Mary","DATE":"2017-03-14"}]}   |
|{"AUTHOR_ID":34,"FIRST_PUBLICATION":["2019-06-16"],"Books":[{"NAME":"Sparrows of Mary","DATE":"2019-06-16"}]}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Spark v3` using `Spark Higher-order functions` is the best solution,

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", [Row(NAME="xs", DATE=datetime.strptime('2022-04-06 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
                                       Row(NAME="s", DATE=datetime.strptime('2022-04-05 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),]), ],
                               'struct<AUTHOR_ID:string,Books:array<struct<NAME:string,DATE:timestamp>>>')
```

`df.show(truncate=False)`

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|AUTHOR_ID|Books                                                |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|1        |[{xs, 2022-04-06 00:00:00}, {s, 2022-04-05 00:00:00}]|
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

`df.printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- AUTHOR_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Books: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

We can get the book with the least date for each author as the following

```
    df = df.withColumn('FIRST_PUBLICATION',
                  f.aggregate(
                      'Books',
                      f.lit(datetime.strptime('2222-02-22 22:22:22', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
                      lambda acc, b : f.least(acc, b['DATE'])
                  )
           )
```

## Result

```
# df.show()
+---------+--------------------+-------------------+
|AUTHOR_ID|               Books|  FIRST_PUBLICATION|
+---------+--------------------+-------------------+
|        1|[{xs, 2022-04-06 ...|2022-04-05 00:00:00|
+---------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 2.4, you can use the [`array_min`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_min.html) function to retrieve the minimum element of an array. You apply this function to an array that contains only the dates. To build the array that contains only dates, you can use [`getField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getField.html) method on `Books` column.

Here is the complete code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('FIRST_PUBLICATION', F.array_min(F.col('Books').getField('DATE')))
```